# Why ASP.NET Membership provider is not Encrypting my password

Tags: asp.net

My Application uses ASP.NET Membership provider. After correct configuration and specifying the Password Format in the Configuration File,Users password are still stored in plain text instead on the Hashed value.
What am i doing wrong?
here is my webcongfigurationfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
```

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="db_connection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.11.10;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=sysad;Password=abc@123_ec"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
    <add assembly="JuiceUI" namespace="Juice" tagPrefix="juice" />
  </controls>
</pages>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="25" />
</authentication>





<membership defaultProvider="Myprovider">
  <providers>
    <add name="Myprovider"
    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
    passwordFormat="Hashed"
    connectionStringName="db_connection"
    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
    enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
     requiresUniqueEmail="false"
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
     minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
     passwordAttemptWindow="10"
     applicationName="" />
  </providers>
</membership>



 </system.web>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I haven't worked on this.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfdhbte0.aspx, and a property named [`HashAlgorithmType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.membershipsection.hashalgorithmtype.aspx) which is used for

> Gets or sets the type of encryption that is used for sensitive
>   membership information.

`<membership defaultProvider="Myprovider" hashAlgorithmType="someValue">`
The "somevalue" can be `SHA1` or `MD5`.

I am sorry, I can't help much on this. This is purely based on looking at the MSDN docs.

Comment: @ shahkalpesh,i did this on my web configuration file

Comment: i have gone through several samples online, they are show similar one as mine

Comment: did you add `HashAlgorithmType` with `SHA1` or `MD5` to your web config?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your <strike>authentication tag</strike> machinekey tag is <strike>incomplete</strike> missing. Read over the following link and let us know how it goes. I had a similar issue with my site and following these tutorials worked like a charm.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-vb

I'd go into more detail but its lunchtime so you're on your own :) Good luck.

---

Edit: I scratched out what I said regarding your authentication tag. I meant you're machinekey tag is missing. The directions for creating it are on the same page as  the authentication tag tutorial and I mixed them up.

Here is the code you need:

```
<configuration>

 <system.web>

 ... Some markup was removed for brevity ...

 <machineKey

 decryption="AES"

 validation="SHA1"

 decryptionKey="1513F567EE75F7FB5AC0AC4D79E1D9F25430E3E2F1BCDD3370BCFC4EFC97A541"

 validationKey="32CBA563F26041EE5B5FE9581076C40618DCC1218F5F447634EDE8624508A129"

 />

 </system.web>

</configuration>
```

The keys listed there are taken from the tutorial site, but you will need to generate your own. They can be generated using one of a few popular random key generators. I would suggest using Steve Gibson's [Perfect Passwords Web Page](https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm).

Comment: @ Lopsided, i will check this nextweek monday,when i resume. today is off day.

Comment: See the updated answer. I knew it was somewhere in that tutorial but I was rushing and mixed them up. Looking back at it, your authentication key looks fine; it's your machinekey tag that needs work.